# Is it valid to ignore an return value of an method in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

For example, when I call a method that returns an value, but I'm not interested in this at all, can I safely ignore that?

Example, instead of:

```
CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:myFont minFontSize:19.0f actualFontSize:&actualFontSize forWidth:150.0f lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

...do this:

```
[str sizeWithFont:myFont minFontSize:19.0f actualFontSize:&actualFontSize forWidth:150.0f lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

I don't need the `CGSize size` but only `actualFontSize`, which is passed in by reference. Now the problem is that XCode gives me a warning if I don't read `size`. I don't want to surpress those warnings, and at the same time I don't want them at all.

So I wonder if it's okay if I just don't assign the return value to anything?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't think Xcode worried about it at all. No, it's not going to do anything bad.

If you want to cleanly shut up the warning, cast the return value to void:

```
(void)[str sizeWithFont:myFont minFontSize:19.0f actualFontSize:&actualFontSize forWidth:150.0f lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2015? Can I ignore my return value? :)

Comment: @Zil, yes, it is still safe, and possibly safer than before.